# pyglet hello world example does not render well

Tags: python, pyglet

What does it mean when the pyglet hello world example, from [here](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blob/pyglet-1.5-maintenance/examples/hello_world.py), does not render well, as in the following screenshot?

[image: Hello world example]

I have another computer, using Ubuntu, where it renders just fine. This one uses Windows.

The other examples such as rendering images and rendering video have the same type of problem as well so it's not about the text per se, or just this example.

I noticed that someone voted to close this for lack of clarity. **Please let me know what more information I can provide.** I just started using pyglet so I am a bit lost as to how to debug some of the issues that come up when using it.

As requested, I am copying the code from the link that I provided into the post:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world!',
                          font_size=36,
                          x=window.width // 2,
                          y=window.height // 2,
                          anchor_x='center',
                          anchor_y='center')


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()


pyglet.app.run()
```

I have tried setting the font explicitly, but as I noted this is a bigger problem, affecting not just text.

Answer (score 1):

When I use my CPU-intel_10875H to run this program ,my image is same as your.I changed my computer GPU mode and selected GPU output only(my GPU is RTX2060) and it solved.Maybe you can change your computer image output mode(CPU or GPU).I'm sure is not a system problem or a program problem.
On my computer,only have to switch "混合模式" to "独显模式"[I'm sorry my computer language is Chinese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWwy7.png)